# Rails cannot find JS file on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sprockets

I have a folder called components in my `app/assets` folder in my Rails app. I am trying to require a js file in a subdirectory of that directory from my `application.coffee` file.

```
#= require holderjs/holder
```

This works in my development environment. But when I deploy to Heroku, it fails with the following error:

```
  Running: rake assets:precompile
  Updating mtimes for current assets...
  rake aborted!
  couldn't find file 'holderjs/holder'
  (in /tmp/build_s0zusz8pduh8/app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee:11)
```

I checked to make sure the components folder is in the assets path of Sprockets on Heroku, and it definitely is. So I can't understand why Heroku cannot find this file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your results of "rake assets:precompile --trace"

Comment: In my development environment, precompiling the assets nothing happens. On Heroku, I get the error above.

Comment: Have you tried adding `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to `config/application.rb`? Running `rake assets:precompile` on Heroku usually fails without that line.

Comment: @redhotvengeance Yes, I did. It doesn't fail for any other file. Only for the files inside components folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that since the folder in the components directory were forked from a git repo, there was a problem for Heroku to track them. I had to remove the .git folder in these directories and push again, and this time it worked.